# remove certain numbers from two dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

```
             dt  AAPL  AMC  AMZN  ASO  ATH  ...  SPCE  SRNE  TH  TSLA  VIAC  WKHS
0    2021-04-12    36   28     6   20    1  ...     5     0   0    50    23     0
1    2021-04-13    46   15     5   16    6  ...     5     0   0   122    12     1
2    2021-04-14    12    4     1    5    2  ...     2     0   0    39     1     0
3    2021-04-15    30   23     3   14    2  ...    15     0   0   101     9     0
```

```
             dt  AAPL  AMC  AMZN  ASO  ATH  ...  SPCE  SRNE  TH  TSLA  VIAC  WKHS
0    2021-04-12    41   28     4   33   10  ...     5     0   0    56    14     3
1    2021-04-13    76   22     7   12   29  ...     4     0   0   134     8     2
2    2021-04-14    21   15     2    7   16  ...     2     0   0    61     3     0
3    2021-04-15    54   43     9    2   31  ...    16     0   0    83    13     1
```

I want to remove numbers from two dataframe that are lower than 10 if the instance is deleted from one dataframe the same cell should be remove in another dataframe same thing goes other way around
Appreciate your help

Comment: no just a cell not the whole row, not the whole column just a cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
## pre-requisite

df1 = df1.set_index('dt')
df2 = df2.set_index('dt')

## processing

mask = df1.lt(10) | df2.lt(10)

df1 = df1.mask(mask)
df2 = df2.mask(mask)
```

output:

```
>>> df1
            AAPL   AMC  AMZN   ASO  ATH  SPCE  SRNE  TH  TSLA  VIAC  WKHS
dt                                                                       
2021-04-12    36  28.0   NaN  20.0  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN    50  23.0   NaN
2021-04-13    46  15.0   NaN  16.0  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN   122   NaN   NaN
2021-04-14    12   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN    39   NaN   NaN
2021-04-15    30  23.0   NaN   NaN  NaN  15.0   NaN NaN   101   NaN   NaN

>>> df2
            AAPL   AMC  AMZN   ASO  ATH  SPCE  SRNE  TH  TSLA  VIAC  WKHS
dt                                                                       
2021-04-12    41  28.0   NaN  33.0  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN    56  14.0   NaN
2021-04-13    76  22.0   NaN  12.0  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN   134   NaN   NaN
2021-04-14    21   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN    61   NaN   NaN
2021-04-15    54  43.0   NaN   NaN  NaN  16.0   NaN NaN    83   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @BENY, I was wondering what was going on while I edited my post ;)

Comment: it gives me an error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: that is how i read these files bearish = pd.read_csv('bearish_comments.csv')
print(bearish)
bullish = pd.read_csv('bullish_comments.csv')
print(bullish)

Comment: @yanbiceps set 'dt' as index on both dataframes, see my update

Comment: or using `read_csv`, add `index_col=0` as argument